# After timestamp is generated, Inserting text beside timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

My idea was when you enter a value in column B, it will generate a timestamp.
The format for the timestamp is "HHmm'H'".
Example: 2310H

The problem is when the timestamp is generated, the suffix "H" was not added.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxvJG.png

My [googlesheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10_KqBzq_QByJzUnoP7Li3onLhXkLbZ9rC65WhzediSM/edit#gid=1745647791)

I have read the google app-script documentation in [Inserting and deleting text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/editing-styling#inserting_and_deleting_text).
Some how I still can't make it work.

My code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
      watchCols = [2],
      offsetCol = [-1],
      ind = watchCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
  if (s.getName() !== "work" || ind === -1) return;
  e.range.offset(0, offsetCol[ind])
  .setValue(new Date());
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      if(vA[i][0]) {
        sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HHmm").appendText("H"); //TIMESTAMP is created, but "H" is not inserted.
      }else{
        sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).clear();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HHmm").appendText("H");
```

#### To:

```
sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HHmm\"H\"");
```

or

```
sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('HHmm"H"');
```

- In this modification, the format of `"HHmm"` was modified. And `appendText("H")` was removed.

#### Note:

- Above modification, the value is put as the date object. If you want to put the value as a string, how about the following modification?

  ```
  sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'HHmm') + "H");
  ```

#### References:

- [setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)
- [ate and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: NICE! it works. Previously I tried setNumberFormat("HHmm'H'"), double quotations marks for the format and single quotations marks. Which did not work. I was thinking in google sheet formula.

I never thought that single quotations marks for the format and double quotations marks would work.

Thanks @Tanaike

Comment: @DeskDespair Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Yes. This situation is different from the formula. In the date format, the double quotation is used. In [the document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats), it's `"text": Displays whatever text is inside the quotation marks as a literal.`.